# Does NServiceBus 4.x with RabbitMQ support round robing consumers or the competing consumer model?

Tags: rabbitmq, nservicebus

I'm using NServiceBus 4.x with RabbitMQ 3.2.x as my transport.
I made the assumption that by using RabbitMQ as my transport I would be given the competing consumer model as an option.  I understand that NServiceBus employs the "Fannout" exchange type for all exchanges and does not support round robin at this time. However is there a way to configure NServiceBus to take advantage of the levels of indirection via Exchanges and channels that RabbitMQ offers.

I have several consumers I would like to compete for messages from a given queue.  What I am observing is subscribers' blocking access to further message retrieval from the queue until the message is consumed.  So having more then one consumer at this point does me no good other then redundancy.

After reading some documentation on RabbitMQ I'm assuming that it's normal to block until the Ack receipt is sent from the subscriber. But I had assumed that subscriber #2 would have free access to the queue to fetch another message.

There is mention of increasing the prefetch count on RabbitMQ channel. 
Example:

```
channel.BasicQos(0,prefetchcount,false)
```

I don't see anywhere that I can change this setting via configuration in NServiceBus.  Furthermore as I read what prefetch does I'm really not sure this what i'm looking for. 
Is it possible to use RabbitMQ with out a distirbutor type pattern used with MSMQ?  Or should I move to MassTransit or Rebus?

Comment: This should definitely be supported. Are you saying that you have multiple endpoints pointing to the same queue but they are not able to process messages concurrently?

Comment: Yes I have multiple NServiceBus.Host.exe's all handling the same event type. In fact they are simply the same host files just spun up in a new process.  I can watch them and they appear to prevent each other from gaining access to the target queue.  Adding more instances of the same host has no affect it appears.  My assumption was that as I spun up several instances of the same host they would compete for access to the queue.

Comment: That sounds strange indeed, would you mind raising an issue on our RabbitMq repo?

Comment: Actually I misread you. You need to increase thr prefetch count since 1 essentially tells rmq to hand out one message at a time:

Comment: Here is how to do it:https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.RabbitMQ/blob/develop/src/NServiceBus.RabbitMQ.Tests/ConnectionString/ConnectionStringParserTests.cs

Comment: Andreas,  Thank you very much for that response!  I'm still not seeing parallel execution per say. But thank you for that reference to the unit tests I had no idea you could set to much in the connection string.  I had seen some earlier referencing to HA with RabbitMQ and connection string settings, but I had no idea there was that much you could configure with Rabbit via that setting.  Thank you!

Comment: Andreas I was under the impression that prefetchcount was used per channel and per client connected to RabbitMQ.  So I think I must have misinterpreted the documentation.

Comment: It appears to be working now.  I think my processing was happening so fast that nothing was queuing up.  I turned my subscribers off queued up 100 messages and I can definitely see parallel execution now with a higher `prefetchcount`.  Thank you...you have answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put prefetchcount=2  in your connection string. Any value above 1 will tell the broker to allow more than X unacked message to go out. You need to fiddle with this setting to find the optimum for your scenario.